# How can I check checkboxes based off class and value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to check checkboxes using jquery, based off class and value. My checkboxes look like this:

```
     <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;margin-right:60px;">
        <label>
          <input class="selSemester" type="checkbox" id="selSemester1" name="selSemester" value="2079">
          Fall
        </label>
     </div>
     <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;margin-right:60px;">
        <label>
          <input class="selSemester" type="checkbox" id="selSemester2" name="selSemester" value="2080">
          Spring
        </label>
     </div>
     <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input class="selSemester" type="checkbox" id="selSemester3" name="selSemester" value="2081">
          Summer
        </label>
     </div>
```

What I was trying to do is this:

```
    $.each(data, function(i, val){

      $(".semesterAwarded input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);

    });
```

Where data is an array that looks like [2079, 2080]. I have tried a few things and can not get something that performs what I am needing. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The class selector should be ".checkbox"

```
$.each(data, function(i, val){

  $(".checkbox input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);

});
```

Here is a working [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/miqiya/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I have other sets of checkboxes on the page. I need a way to distinguish between them.

Comment: That's no problem, you can just change the class on your <div> elements from "checkbox" to something else. Here's an example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/miqiya/3/edit?html,js,output) where it's changed to "myUniqueClass"

Comment: The problem was going to be I had two sets or groups of checkboxes that had the same values on them. I am going to use this though and just change the values and how I am getting that data. THanks